# JavaScript Jquery homework issue wont work with anything but optimal values for variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trouble shooting this for a while and I'm totally confused as to why this program is not working properly. I am taking an introductory JavaScript course so I'm sure it probably something obvious that I missed but any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

this is the javascript/jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            salary: "required",
            creditScore: "required",
            months: "required"

        },
        messages: {
            salary:"salary is required",
            creditScore:"credit score is required",
            months: " months is required"
        }

    });

    $("#form1").submit(function(){

    });  

    $('#verify').click(function() {
        'use strict'
        var form = $("#form1");
        form.validate();

        if (form.valid()) {
            var salary = $("#salary").val();

            var creditScore = $("#creditScore").val();

            var months = $("#months").val();

            var result;
            console.log (salary);
            console.log (creditScore);
            console.log (months);
            if ( salary >= 40000 ) 
            {
                if(creditScore >= 600 || months > 12)
                {
                    result = "Loan approved";
                }
            } 
            else if (salary  < 40000 ) 
            {
                if (creditScore >= 600 && months > 12)
                {
                    result = "Loan approved.";
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                result = "Loan denied.";
            }

            console.log(result);
            $('#output').val(result);

            return false;
            }

    });
});
```

and this is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="LoanProcess.js"></script>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label for="salary">salary: </label>
    <input type="text" name="salary" id="salary">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="creditScore">creditScore: </label>
    <input type="text" name="creditScore" id="creditScore">
  </p>
    <p>
    <label for="months">months: </label>
    <input type="text" name="months" id="months">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="verify" id="verify" value="Verify">
  </p>  
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="output" id="output" value="">
  </p>  

</form>
<div id="result">
</div>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you define "not working properly"?

Comment: What is the javascript not doing?

Comment: sure I apologize for not being more clear, I used firebug to debug and its assigning the values fine from the form, and If i enter in optimal ranges such as 40000 for salary 600 for credit or 12 for months it spits out loan approved as expected. But when I start playing with the values to get the other results based on my nested Ifs it errors out. The only clue from debugger is it says line 57 console.log(result); is undefined when the values are changed

Comment: odd i linked the html that goes with it but its not showing in the question now

Comment: Take your comment above about what isn't working, edit your question and add that info along with a description of your program and how it should behave.

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/A4Rg3/

Comment: trying to link the problem but its on schools blackboard cant link it save it copy it or anything because its just a flow chart they gave me to follow

Comment: Look at to see what happens if the salary is less than 40000 in your click handler? It looks like result isn't set in one case.

Comment: thanks tieson for your fiddle which made his explanation alot easier to understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of notes:

- your script tags are out of head tag and before body - they have to be inside one or another
- body and html tags are both closed twice
- if you want to use `'use strict'` usually you put it as the first line of the module, even if it is totally legal to put it inside function , it doesn't make much sense in your case
- if you do not need submit handler for your form, remove it
- good practice with jquery is to cache selectors that you are going to use more than once:
- $().val() returns you string, so you have to convert it to number first, before comparing with numbers, use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), `parseFloat`, `+x`, `x | 0` or some other method which is appropriate in your case
- you have to add `load denied` messae in case outer condition is true but inner is not

consider example:

```
$(function() {
  var form = $('#form')
    , $salary = $("#salary")
    , $creditScore = $("#creditScore")
    , $months = $("#months")
    , verify = $('#verify')

  form.validate(...)

  verify.on('click', function(e) {

     form.validate()

     if (form.valid()) {

        // I belive you are waiting for integers more than a zero
        // so using `x | 0`  you are getting 0 or integer
        var salary = $salary.val() | 0
          , creditScore = $creditScore.val() | 0
          , months = $months.val() | 0
        // now you have numbers so your comparison would number with number not string with string
        ...

     }


  })

})
```

Also thanks to @Tieson T there is a fiddle, which seem to be doing what you want http://jsfiddle.net/A4Rg3/2/

Comment: creditScore >= 600 && months > 12 one is an or and one is an and, and thats based on wether or not salary is >=4000 or < 4000 or did I do that wrong?

Comment: ooohh yah , I was using an example where we just validated strings. gonna have to add a number validator too, so must of it is correct I jsut need to do the conversion?

Comment: got it now I jsut need to remember how to check that its a number in the validator otherwise works great thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Verify your conditions, for some of them you didn't specified else statement that thould set the result.

Eg.

```
if ( salary >= 40000 ) 
{
    if(creditScore >= 600 || months > 12)
    {
        result = "Loan approved";
    }
    // missing else-statement
    else {
        result = "Loan denied";
    }
}
...
```

You don't actually need another level of if clauses, you can write:

```
if (salary >= 40000 && (creditScore >= 600 || months > 12)) {
     result = "Loan approved.";
}
else if (salary  < 40000 && (creditScore >= 600 && months > 12)) {
     result = "Loan approved.";
}
else {
     result = "Loan denied.";
}
```

or

```
if (
     (salary >= 40000 && (creditScore >= 600 || months > 12))  ||
     (salary  < 40000 && (creditScore >= 600 && months > 12))
){
     result = "Loan approved.";
} else {
     result = "Loan denied.";
}
```

Comment: great help as well, though from the start I was using strings instead of numbers which was the root of the problem. The fiddle fixed both errors for me.